# Group 3 tables by max date

Tags: mysql, join, max

A customer can make many inquiries, and an inquiry can have many updates. I'm trying to view each inquiry and the latest update. I'm able to pull the latest date but not the update that's relevant to it. I've seen answers similar to mine but they only seem to deal with one join and I don't understand how I can use those to find a solution.

Here's my sql

```
select c.name, i.inquirycontent, u.updatecontent, max(u.date) from inquiries i
inner join customers c on c.customerid = i.customerid
left join updates u on u.inquiryid = i.inquiryid
group by i.inquiryid
```

Even if I omit the customer table, I am still unable to match the latest update to its content. How can I do this?

edit - as requested, here is some sample data

```
+------------+------+
| customerid | name |
+------------+------+
| 1          | jeff |
+------------+------+
| 2          | anne |
+------------+------+

+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| inquiryid | inquirycontent  | customerid |
+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| 1         | inquiry1content | 1          |
+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| 2         | inquiry2content | 1          |
+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| 3         | inquiry3content | 2          |
+-----------+-----------------+------------+

+----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
| updateid | updatecontent   | inquiryid | date     |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
| 1        | update1content  | 1         | 01-01-17 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
| 2        | update2content  | 1         | 03-01-17 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
| 3        | update3content  | 3         | 04-01-17 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
```

And here's what I want the query to output -

```
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
| name | inquirycontent  | latestupdate   | date     |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
| jeff | inquiry1content | update2content | 03-01-17 |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
| jeff | inquiry2content | NULL           | NULL     |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
| anne | inquiry3content | update3content | 04-01-17 |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: please post a few rows of your table

Comment: How do I format this?

Comment: indent 4 spaces and try to make it look nice, like codeblock

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude solution using UNION, but it works for what I need. The first select finds all unique inquiries by their latest update, and the second select finds all rows that haven't yet been updated.

```
(select c.name, i.inquirycontent, u.updatecontent, t2.mxdate
from updates u
inner join inquiries i on i.inquiryid = u.inquiryid
inner join customers c on c.customerid = i.customerid
inner join
(
  select max(u.date) mxdate, i.inquiryid
  from updates u
  left join inquiries i on i.inquiryid = u.inquiryid
  group by i.inquiryid
) t2
  on u.inquiryid = t2.inquiryid
  and u.date = t2.mxdate)
UNION
(select c.name, i.inquirycontent, u.updatecontent, u.date 
from inquiries i
left join updates u on u.inquiryid = i.inquiryid
inner join customers c on c.customerid = i.customerid
where u.updatecontent is NULL)
```